# Force show bootstrap tooltip using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking everywhere, is there any way to force show the tooltip, not using an event, but using a js code, because we all know the flaw of numerical input and the paste exploit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var previous;
//Buy Button JS code
$(function () {
    $("#searchform").bind('submit', function () {
        var str = $('#search-form').val();
        if (str.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
            //Great, continue executing the script.
        }
        else
        {
            //Force show a tooltip asking the user to numerically type the text.
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To trigger a tooltip to show up you need to use the `'show'`  option of the tooltip. Here is an example.

`$('#element').tooltip('show')`

Replace `#element` with your own selector.

To add title using Jquery itself you can do this

`$('#element').tooltip({title:"test title"})`

Comment: Thank you, you answered both questions :)

Answer (score 3):

To show tooltip

```
$('#youtooltip').tooltip('show');
```

Your code:

```
var previous;
//Buy Button JS code
$(function () {
    $("#searchform").bind('submit', function () {
        var str = $('#search-form').val();
        if (str.match(/^[0-9]*$/)) {
            //Great, continue executing the script.
        }
        else
        {
            $('#youtooltipid').tooltip('show');
            // or $('.youtooltipclass').tooltip('show');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```